# How can I combine multiple similar methods into one that returns three results?

Tags: c#

I have two methods that are very similar:

```
    public static int GetSelectedThemeOf2()
    {
        return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? 0 : 1; 
    }

    public static bool IsLightModeSelected()
    {
        return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? true : false;
    }

    public static string GetSelectedMode()
    {
        return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? "Dark" : "Light";
    }
```

is there some way I could combine all three into one and then return either

```
    0, true, "Dark"
```

or

```
    1, false, "Light"
```

Comment: What's the point here? Not to repeat the logic?

Comment: To simplify.  If it comes to the time when I want to add some different logic then I would like to add it all in the one place.  Very possible that "GetSelectedThemeOf4()" will change for example.

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? C# 7 introduces a new syntax for tuples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C# 7 You can achieve it using tuple.** [Snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XVYu2U)

```
public static int GetSelectedThemeOf2()
{
    return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? 0 : 1; 
}

public static bool IsLightModeSelected()
{
    return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? true : false;
}

public static string GetSelectedMode()
{
    return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? "Dark" : "Light";
}

public static (int t2, bool lightMode, string mode) GetSelectedTheme()
{
    return ( GetSelectedThemeOf2(), IsLightModeSelected(), GetSelectedMode());
}

public static void Main()
{
    var theme = GetSelectedTheme();
    Console.WriteLine( theme.mode );
}
```

**Output**

```
Light
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe make one method that holds the core logic in one place and some to "translate" the results in different formats.

```
public static bool IsLightModeSelected()
{
    return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? true : false;
}

public static int GetSelectedThemeOf2()
{
    return IsLightModeSelected() ? 0 : 1; 
}

public static string GetSelectedMode()
{
    return IsLightModeSelected() ? "Dark" : "Light";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe look at a Tuple.

you then can return

`Tuple<int, bool, string>` you can get the items like this

```cs
Tuple<int, bool, string> r = Tuple.Create(0, true, "Dark");
r.item1; // 0
r.item2; // true
r.item3; // "Dark"
```

Example

```cs
public static Tuple<int, bool, string> getData(){
    int theme = GetSelectedThemeOf2();
    bool light = IsLightModeSelected();
    string mode = GetSelectedMode();
    return Tuple.Create(theme, light, mode);
}
```

Cheers

EDIT: added a example

Comment: Can you give an example of how this could be used to combine the three methods I have into one called GetSelectedTheme.

Comment: Added a example

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
public Tuple<int, bool, string> GetTupple()
{
   return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2 ? Tuple.Create(0, true, "Dark") : Tuple.Create(1, false, "Light");
}
```

Here's how you can access the members:

```
var myTuple = GetTuple() // this returns the Tuple, see GetTuple declaration

Console.WriteLine(myTupple.Item1);
Console.WriteLine(myTupple.Item2);
Console.WriteLine(myTupple.Item3);
```

Comment: How would I access the Tuple members in a call to GetTupple?

Comment: You can't access Tuple members in a call.. you must first call the Method to return the tuple, which is what is requested on the question. you could do `(GetTuple()).Item1` ... or just save the Tuple on a variable `var myTuple = GetTuple();`

Comment: I have added more code to show you how you can use it after calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples):

```
public static (int themeOf2, bool lightModeSelected, string selectedMode) GetModes()
{
    var themeOf4 = GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2;
    return (themeOf4 ? 0 : 1,
            themeOf4,
            themeOf4 ? "Dark" : "Light");
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var modes = GetModes();
Console.WriteLine(modes);
Console.WriteLine(modes.themeOf2);
Console.WriteLine(modes.lightModeSelected);
Console.WriteLine(modes.selectedMode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify it like this:

```
    public static int GetSelectedThemeOf2()
    {
        return Comparison() ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static bool IsLightModeSelected()
    {
        return Comparison() ? true : false;
    }

    public static string GetSelectedMode()
    {
        return Comparison() ? "Dark" : "Light";
    }

    private static bool Comparison()
    {
        return GetSelectedThemeOf4() < 2;
    }
```